# How can I store the value of Current Date Into su.date?

Tags: c, string, struct

```
struct s
{
    char date[100];

}su;

char *formateddate()
{
   static char result[100];
   time_t t;
   t = time(NULL);
   strftime(result, sizeof(result), "%Y-%m-%d", localtime(&t));
   return result;
}



void main()
{
    char *currentDate=formateddate();
    printf("%s",currentDate);
    //su.date=currentDate;

}
```

Error: assignment to expression with array type.

I am trying to return current date and store it to the su.date .How can i store it and use further ?

Comment: It’s a string; use `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `strcopy` to copy into the array.

```c
strcopy(su.date, currentDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strcpy(su.date, currentDate)` instead of assignment, or probably better pass su.date as argument to formatteddate().